# Why is Descartes' Rule of Signs Not Working Here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x^7-6x^6-6x^5-12x^4+29x^3+36x^2+36x+42=0$

I keep getting that there are a maximum of 2 positive real solutions using the rule of signs, but I know that there are 4 - the cube root of 6 (three times) and 7. Why is Descartes' Rule of Signs not working in this case?

EDIT: Question answered, completely blanked out on the last possibility using a cubic...

Comment: What makes you think that the cube root of $6$ is a triple zero?

Comment: Completely blanked out there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you only have $2$ positive roots. Your polynomial is equal to
$$
(x+1)\left(x^2+1\right)(x-7)\left(x^3-6\right),
$$
whose only positive roots are $7$ and $\sqrt[3]6$. The remaing real root is $-1$ and there are four complex non-real roots: $i$, $-i$, $\sqrt[3]6\left(-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)$, and $\sqrt[3]6\left(-\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)$.

Comment: Where did you get the last two answers from? Isn't the cube root of 6 a triple root?

Comment: @techr cube root of 6 is an incomplete solution of $x^3-6=0$

Comment: @techr The cube root of 6 is a triple root IF there is a factor of $ ( x - a ) ^3$ where $ a = \sqrt[3]{6}$. That is not the case here.

Comment: @techr Since the cube roots of $1$ are $1$, $-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i$, and $-\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2i$, the cube roots of $6$ are $\sqrt[3]6$, $\sqrt[3]6\left(-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)$, and $\sqrt[3]6\left(-\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)$.